# Elixir - Postgres: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\

Tags: postgresql, elixir

I'm currently working on an elixir project that parses XML from an API and inserts data into postgres using postgrex.

Most inserts work fine, however for the odd insert I get this error. I've seen a lot of other people facing this error, but I'm not to sure how to solve it in Elixir.

```
23:52:32.402 [error] Process #PID<0.224.0> raised an exception
** (KeyError) key :constraint not found in: %{code: :character_not_in_repertoire, file: "wchar.c", line: "2011", message: "invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xe3 0x83 0x22", pg_code: "22021", routine: "report_invalid_encoding", severity: "ERROR"}
    (pipeline_processor) lib/worker.ex:133: PipelineProcessor.Worker.recursive_db_insert/1
    (pipeline_processor) lib/worker.ex:47: PipelineProcessor.Worker.process_article/1
    (pipeline_processor) lib/worker.ex:17: PipelineProcessor.Worker.request_article/0
```

I'm aware that the error is actually due to accessing an invalid property of the map. However I'm trying to solve the issue that postgrex is giving.

My postgrex insert code:

```
sql_string = "INSERT INTO articles (title, source, content) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id"
{:ok, pid} = Postgrex.Connection.start_link(Application.get_env(:pipeline_processor, :db_details))
response = Postgrex.Connection.query(
  pid,
  sql_string,
  [article.title, article.source, article.content]
)

Postgrex.Connection.stop(pid)
```

Is there anyway in Elixir to scrub out invalid bytes so that these inserts can succeed? Or for some way to have postgres handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already guessed postgres is complaining that you are inserting invalid UTF8 into a text type. I would initially try to fix the bad encodings if you cannot do that you can use a combination of `String.codepoints/1` and `String.valid_character?/1` to either scrub or escape the invalid bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot.